# Help with Triggered sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Though this question seems to irrelevant to most of the professionals but I am in need to send out triggered emails via marketing cloud but in order to send out real time triggers such that as soon as a subscribers comes in to the DE or List it should fire an email. I have discussed and came to a conclusion that this can't be done via UI. the only thing I can do is to use API calls.

I have idea about Java but not sure how to connect Marketing cloud instance with Eclipse or any other IDE. 
I have already integrated Eclipse to my Salesforce service could with the help of some documents but not sure how to connect Marketing cloud with eclipse so that I can use API to send trigger emails.

Any help document or if someone guide me to the correct learning material would be a great help.
I have little knowledge about API calls.

Comment: Can't help you with the API integration. However, if it's just an automated mail when entering a list that can be done with a welcome mail (which is defined on the list itself). 
Unfortunately this option is not available for Data Extensions. Depending on your setup and the type of automation you want to create, much can also be done with Automation Studio (and even more so with Journey Builder).

Comment: Are you familiar with SOAP APIs in general?

Comment: @christoffer I am aware of the UI and as far as I know if I use a filtered DE which refreshes every 2 minutes and use it in a journey I can't schedule it for less than 1 hour. while I was looking for a solution that pushes message or email to the subscriber as soon as they enter the DE via import activity.

Answer (score 1):

This page in the documentation covers Triggered Sends: [**Triggered Email Scenario Guide For Developers**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.htm)

In it's simplest form, you can do a form POST to an SFMC endpoint with an XML SOAP envelope like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-f4119202-0c6f-4383-9872-4745b39f24f6-1">
            <o:Username>XXXXX</o:Username>
            <o:Password>XXXXX</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
            <QueuePriority>High</QueuePriority>
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <TriggeredSendDefinition>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey>ETWSEX_TSD</CustomerKey>
            </TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <Subscribers>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <EmailAddress>example@example.com</EmailAddress>
               <SubscriberKey>example@example.comm</SubscriberKey>
               <Attributes>
                  <Name>FromName</Name>
                  <Value>From John Doe</Value>
               </Attributes>
               <Attributes>
                  <Name>HTML__Content</Name>
                  <Value>&lt;b>Sent Asynchronously!&lt;/b></Value>
               </Attributes>
            </Subscribers>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If you'd like to utilize [**the Java SDK**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm) that SFMC provides, you can also do it that way, but it's more involved.

If you're familiar with REST APIs, then you can also trigger emails with SFMC's [**REST API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm).

Comment: Just a heads up: that is a legacy xml block, not SOAP, and will likely be sunset. There is an example SOAP envelope here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/submitting_a_triggered_send_definition_using_the_asynchronous_api.htm

Comment: You're right.  Updated my answer with a proper envelope.  You're talking about the sunset of the XML API, right?  Or are there plans to deprecate the SOAP?

Comment: Correct. We'd have a riot on our hands if soap went away(not to mention a lot of broken clients). :)